# /dev/log/main not found

Tags: android, debugging, logcat

I'm trying to develop an Android application but when I try to connect to logcat I get the following error:

> Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory

I already installed a new SDK, rebooted my phone... nothing seems to solve the problem. Anyone has any solution?

Samsung Galaxy S (Darky's v9.1)

Apple OSX

ADB 1.0.26

Comment: By connecting to logcat you mean issuing a `add logcat` command?

Comment: What does the output of `adb shell ls -l /dev/log` look like?

Comment: /dev/log: No such file or directory... I tried creating the files using the terminal, but after reboot they were gone...

Comment: Those are special system files which can't just be created. Very weird tho. So the entire log directory is missing?

Comment: Indeed... I read something about it has to be enabled in the kernel, however i talked to Darky and he said its no kernel problem... (His words, not mine...)

Comment: It seems this is related to kernel of the rom. Is there any solution to this `Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main` error with Franco kernel?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6941710/unable-to-open-log-device-dev-log-main-no-such-file-or-directory#comment26412708_17516198

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had used the Speedmod kernel; This has default Logging disabled. Re-enabled it in the TWEAKS menu.

Thanks for making me realise this Octavian Damiean

Comment: Btw, to access Speedmod kernel tweaks you have to restart in recovery mode.

Answer (score 7):

I found the following method on XDA:

```
adb shell
su
mount -o remount,rw /system
echo ANDROIDLOGGER >> /system/etc/tweaks.conf
mount -o remount,ro /system
```

and reboot.

Answer (score 2):

For a rooted Galaxy Note 7000, run insmod /lib/modules/logger.ko in the shell (this is missing from the rootfs' init.rc), assuming you can boot up sufficiently far to access adb / some terminal like terminal-ide. The module mounts in /dev/log and provides the missing files.

Comment: This did it! But you have to type "insmod /system/lib/modules/logger.ko"!

Comment: i have the same issu, i don't undestand how to fix that? i type type "insmod /system/lib/modules/logger.ko" where?