# Launch application when device turn on or unlocked

Tags: android, events

1.How to launch/open application when the device is just open?

2.How to launch/open application when the device is just unlocked/exit from lock state?

(I mean, how to recognize these events?)

10q,

David

This is my new code:

In Manifest:

```
<receiver
  android-permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
  android:name="BootReciver" >
  <intent-filter >
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
      <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

In BootReciver.java I added to my project:

```
package development.Grandpa;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;

    public class BootReciver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intent1 = new Intent(context, Grandpa.class);
        context.startActivity(intent1);      
    }
}
```

Where Grandpa class is my Main Activity.

In addition, I'm running the code directlly on my device and that is what I'm getting in the LogCat:

??-?? ??:??:??.???: INFO/(): Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory

I also tried to add one reciver for boot and another one for ScreenOn (with two classes) like this:

```
<receiver
android:name="ScreenOnReciver" >
    <intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
</intent-filter>
</receiver>

<receiver
android-permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
android:name="BootReciver" >
<intent-filter >
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
</intent-filter>
 </receiver>
```

But it didn't help also.

Edit:

This it what I'm getting in logcat after:

1.Run the application

2.Exit from the application

3.Lock Screen

4.Unlock Screen

```
11-13 23:59:26.140: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3640): Set to default setting_6 : region=-   Duser.region=IL propRegn=IL
11-13 23:59:26.710: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(3649): Set to default setting_6 : region=-Duser.region=IL propRegn=IL
11-13 23:59:33.246: ERROR/power(244): *** set_screen_state 0
11-13 23:59:33.246: ERROR/SensorManager(244): unregisterListener:: all sensors,    listener = com.android.server.PowerManagerService$13@40517118
11-13 23:59:33.593: ERROR/LockPatternKeyguardView(244): Phone is boot completed. so can   send broadcast message for music player
11-13 23:59:35.286: ERROR/power(244): *** set_screen_state 1
11-13 23:59:35.286: ERROR/SensorManager(244): registerListener :: handle = 3  name=     GP2A Light Sensor delay= 200000 Listener=   com.android.server.PowerManagerService$13@40517118
11-13 23:59:35.286: ERROR/SensorManager(244): reg :: handle = 3
11-13 23:59:35.336: ERROR/LockPatternKeyguardView(244): Phone is boot completed. so can  send broadcast message for music player
11-13 23:59:36.360: ERROR/SlidingTab(244): onTouchEvent() : thresholdReached !
11-13 23:59:36.380: ERROR/KeyguardViewMediator(244): Phone is boot completed. so can   broadcast
11-13 23:59:36.400: ERROR/MTPRx(3319): In MtpReceiverandroid.intent.action.USER_PRESENT
11-13 23:59:36.410: ERROR/MTPRX(3319): Battery charging. plugType = 2
11-13 23:59:36.410: ERROR/MTPRx(3319): USB charging
11-13 23:59:36.416: ERROR/MTPRx(3319): usb is connected, set value in Settings.System,   result = true
11-13 23:59:36.416: ERROR/MTPRx(3319): usb mode = 0
11-13 23:59:36.416: ERROR/MTPRx(3319): usb debugging is enabled
```

Edit2:

I have only these "Exception" in the logcat:

```
11-14 00:22:15.313: WARN/WindowManager(244): android.view.InflateException: Binary XML  file line #7: Error inflating class <unknown>
11-14 00:22:15.313: WARN/WindowManager(244): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
11-14 00:22:15.313: WARN/WindowManager(244): Caused by:   android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource is not a Drawable (color or   path): TypedValue{t=0x2/d=0x1010059 a=-1}
```

Comment: I don't know why you are getting that log error, but I believe it is unrelated to this question. Either search for a solution or post a new question.

Comment: I fix this problem according to:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867971/dev-log-main-not-found

Comment: That log is not the stack trace. Look for lines that say "Exception at ..."

Comment: Hi Craigy, Is it possible to ask you for a working example code via private mail?

Comment: No, because I do not have a working example and then others would not be able to benefit from the process of working through your problems on SO. The error you currently face is spelled out in the logcat exception you posted. You are using a resource that is not a drawable in line 7 of one of your XML files.

Comment: Craigy, I think you wrong. I made an HelloWorld Application, with the above receiver code and I got the same error on boot. (And same nothing on screen on)

Answer (score 7):

What you want to do is set up a BroadcastReceiver that listens for those actions. More information:

- http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html#Components
- http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/BroadcastReceiver.html
- http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/02/02/custom-intents-and-broadcasting-with-receivers/

for your situation you would have a receiver

```
public class YourReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, YourActivity.class);
        context.startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

and register it in your manifest:

```
    <receiver
        android-permission="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"
        android:name="YourReceiver" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

Comment: Hi Craigy, 10x for the answer and the links. One more queation, where do I have to put the code above? In a seperate project? or in the same project?

Comment: It will be in the same project. You will create a new Java class for the receiver, and add the `<receiver>` tag into your AndroidManifest.xml file inside the `<application>` tag.

Comment: e.g: I have Application Project called 'A'. and in this project i want to add a code that everytime the device turn on or unlock the application ('A') will open. Can it be done using the above concepts?

Comment: Hi again, the "startActivity(intent)" is not recognize, how to fix it?

Comment: Good call, it should be `context.startActivity(intent)`

Comment: Hi, I have few problems with the code above: 1.When I unlock the device nothing heppend/ the appliction not running. 2.when boot the device I'm getting an error msg like "Sorry, can't open your application...".    What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try using the complete package names for the receivers, so use `development.Grandpa.BootReciver` in the Manifest file. Also, you are misspelling "receiver". It shouldn't matter as long as you are consistent but make sure you get the names right wherever you use them.

Comment: I did the above changes, In boot I'm still getting an error msg like: "The application Grandpa (development.Grandpa process) stop unexpectedly. Try again".   And where screen is on nothing happend. Do I miss permission like RECEIVE_SCREEN_ON?

Comment: You should get a stacktrace in logcat, please post the exception you are getting

Comment: I'm new to android/Eclipse... which lines in the logcat D/E/...? (I have ~400 rows there)

Comment: OK, here it is [Click here](https://picasaweb.google.com/116950027034399434688/November132011?authuser=0&authkey=Gv1sRgCKqqyLy4o6vV1gE&feat=directlink)

Comment: Post it in your original question as code, it is unreadable as images.