# Start android app after bluetooth connection

Tags: android, bluetooth, startup

Is it possible to start an app in case of an bluetooth connection to a specific device? Maybe the application have to run in background. In this case i want to open a specific view or activity after the bluetooth connection!?

Comment: Did you made this to work correctly? Can you provide little code snippet of broadcast receiver? I'm stuck with this and dont know how to launch the app.. I would be grateful..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a braodcast receiver which listens to bluetooth connection and in `onReceive` check if connection is with the device you need. If so, then open your app from the broadcast using the intent.

action in manifest for your receiver

```
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.adapter.action.STATE_CHANGED" />
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.UUID" />
<action android:name="android.bluetooth.device.action.BOND_STATE_CHANGED" />
```

permissions to be given

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Comment: Can you provide little code snippet of broadcast receiver? I'm stuck with this and dont know how to launch the app..

Comment: for details see this Q/A http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8073053/launch-application-when-device-turn-on-or-unlocked