# Unable to access Logcat on Nexus 4

Tags: android, logcat

When I try to access the logcat of my phone with `adb logcat`, it gives me the error `Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory`

I found a couple solutions (such as [/dev/log/main not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867971/dev-log-main-not-found)), but none I found worked. Also, I'd prefer not to root in order to fix this.

The device is a Nexus 4 running stock Android 4.2.2.

Answer (score 0):

Have you enabled developer options on your device?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vlA9MIjv8Jw

Comment: Yes, I'm able to upload debug applications and run them just fine.