# adb logcat does not work: /dev/log/main not found

Tags: android, adb, logcat, motorola

I have a first gen Moto G with this [rom](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/development/rom-4-4-4-stock-eu-1-click-easy-flash-t2879757) and logcat does not work. I get the error message

> Unable to open log device '/dev/log/main': No such file or directory

I have already tried the following suggestions, but to no avail:

- Dialing *#*#2846579#*#* does not do anything
- logcat-enable in adb shell
- i looked for the logger.ko module everywhere but did not find it

Does anyone have a solution?

Comment: The same question is asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4867971/dev-log-main-not-found

Comment: Unfortunatly, none of the solutions in this thread work on my phone.

Comment: I got a solution - stop using broken builds

Comment: Indeed the rom was the problem. I installed [this one](http://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-g/development/rom-cyanogenmod-11-aerokernel-t2853317) and now it works.